# clique inequality

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm new in graph theory and a bit puzzled by the syntax. I have problems understanding the clique inequality

$
\sum_{v\in C}x_v \leq 1
$

Anyone care to explain why this makes sense?

[image]

From the general description of cliques, I understand that, if we enumerate from the upper left corner and go clockwise, the set of vertices {1,2,3} form a clique. But I don't see how $x_1+x_2+x_3 \leq 1$? As far as I understand the syntax they sum up to three, since $x_v = 1$ if chosen and else 0. Obviously my understanding of the syntax is wrong. Anyone care to elaborate?

Thanks

Comment: This seems to be missing a lot of context. Are you trying to find a maximal independent set or something?

Comment: No, just a clique in the graph. And as I understand the definition of a clique, this could for instance be the node set {1,2,3} with the enumeration described above. It's a clique, because each node in the set has a connecting edge to the other nodes. But I also know that for cliques, the clique inequality has to hold..

Comment: In that case, please copy the definition of $x_v$ from your textbook, notes, or whatever source you're using to study graph theory.

Comment: http://www.rebennack.net/files/papers/Reb08a.pdf page 7

Answer (score 1):

The notes you're working from are about solving the stable set problem, also known as the independent set problem. $x_i$ is a variable introduced in a 0-1 linear programming formulation, corresponding to vertex $i$ being in the independent set. If two vertices from a clique are in a set then it is not independent, because by the definition of a clique there is an edge between the two vertices. Therefore at most one vertex from the clique is included in an independent set, which is expressed as the inequality you state.

This equality is therefore fundamentally about the independent set problem, and doesn't make sense *outside that context*.

Comment: Ahh, then it makes more sense. Thanks!